# JQuery Mobile trigger create

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've injected a header into my DOM and I would like JQM to render the header:

```
<div data-role="page" id="start">
    <div data-role="header" class="header">
        <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am calling

> $('body').trigger('create')

but this doesn't update the HTML and the header doesn't render properly.

What am I doing wrong?

If I do this for a button it works fine:

```
<div data-role="page" id="start">
    <a class="mybutton" href="javascript:;" data-role="button" id="uid-1">TEST</a>
</div>
```

> $('body').trigger('create')
>   updates to :

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="mypage" id="start" data-url="start" tabindex="0"
    class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 620px;">
    <a
        class="mybutton ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c"
        href="javascript:;" data-role="button" id="uid-1"
        data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true"
        data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span
            class="ui-btn-text">TEST</span></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

Since you're injecting items dynamically into page, use

```
.trigger('pagecreate')
```

to enhance full page contents.

Comment: Is there a way to process all HTML in the entire body eg header, footer, buttons etc.

Comment: @dd. it's possible. Check this demo I have created before for dynamic pages. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/FaT7S/

Comment: Your suggestion doesnt appear to work for me...it just changes the text to 'new header'. I'm using JQM 1.3.0.

Comment: @DD. you could inject all content and then refresh the same page using `$.mobile.changePage('#pageID', function () { allowSamePageTransition: true });`

Comment: $.mobile.changePage("#start",function () { allowSamePageTransition: true }))........I get undefined error

Comment: @DD. Page _#start_ was active when you called this function?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27286/discussion-between-omar-and-dd)